# could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}' typescript error

Tags: typescript

I am seeing this error a hell of a lot after upgrading to typescript 3.5.

> could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}' typescript error

I have no idea what it means and it is always referring to the empty `{}` type.

If you look at [this playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PQKhCgAIUhlAXAhgOwCaIDYHtkFNK4AeiAtgA4b5YBmkAKgJ5m4AKATlmQM6TwAWieJADGKSACN8bAK7JIASzmJILDIgYBzDrNRQI0SAEFhAa2RYA7pVQbcJXMngAuPZAC0kAALoN6AIyQ1FhsvHz4XKQU+MJYqPj88jwWiDzB8hqKmBgMEim4qJA4kCgF-Pjycco0xYGywvDBhQBuuCEABnQA-G2uHp4kKYi4+dKBjWWQEeSUIrHxWLy4XEITmBpp-CRcvV7IiOj2o0EhYRhkkBby-KHRwfhxXOnIesDge-ZcZIjC+GRYwpAAN5QSCg4DASAAMTqDTYINBingrWo33wCEE8mE0OQ9WCAB4AOIAPiB8NB5IGZDxkIIhCRaB4BIcrUxhKJABpIABVIkACjJ5MFvDYKC4xxITkgvMQkpYiBF9iRbC41KJAG0AAwAXQAlJAALwkrnsgVC0GUr7iSiSyGm0E6yVMvBsVmQzlqrlaokAbjJAF9wGTwZAAKLEaZLMkxZDLYpsEUMbG4tiS9HwTFJ2F4lAMNVeg2ks3mxBkSV4wycgBCfOoyEl0slhj1hsglc5KMbeYdrbzBpJwKLQrYuHg0jYchRADpKbzazrfYOA4K-QvydHY1hxAArXD1TPBVNIdNYmH4zc7+ok-WFouUssV1s1utSmVGZsktuBV9NyWVvs3wdQWHUdx0CZBZ0Qec7UgJdyRXKMcFjZBpAwNQrVwfcUzgI8M1PNg8XPXchAAH0gZDUMgUidFwahFHyK8AKFO9IHLKs+WgwVa3rb931bE1APJDsjEosiUIwETqNovBdEHbs-1I8jxKotAaLogoWwHATIGAscJ2UABCa9JLUyBOjAiC9UlFFVzNWDQXghCYyEVAsGkdCQmvXlCElZCSEkNheMIAwACZfUc2NCB4a95QTTDpxLXkXLcyg2HdAAWTlgt1b1IGDSKfOkPzWjzcKhCC69CL3PD4rIRLXPczk0uC+dcohbzRKKuFBXXMqADkxILRTEHQuKZyShrRNQlq8v61CCtQ0rIEIWAsHsQaxOGyhRoS8aUsa4oeF8-yJJUqT8mmtqVvsArOpOuIzt0RbqDww8MRPHEs1kMxLDkUiczzBjNLNGda3bSDGMHHTQMMeN1EnRIYYTCyOKLMyYvUbbatBr8dRRs0rIMozTrUvHALMyr4Ex2dkDB3GtMA+a0K26qQZpnGbKFOyYLC7rEKEBgotqD7ghqurktadLMuy1rIAFm7-JK3mnNlgtnuFthRd2iXICai7Zfl1pFoYWbxOvNXk01+q9smjA9eNsTGaNq78DNlmdqt7WmoOjrjuU+61Lt52DZCP3VOkwNBWDOgliEVz4DIaR4AjtdEKwShJ2wDReQAIjoQwWEgFplXkIo-AAZmzqCla4NPcAzrAs+zgBiegmFYDhuBUDhqmqABhHAfjIeBK459da-rxu-EnScAA4R+T0Ex-TzP+UHSLNS1A19WvGfIAAMj3pauDVPxN+3680tMyBs6wExIACdGckpbPIElbPzFju+H9hp+S2zskq4pxjOPFe5Vt6QBnpfMyN877BUKNuIikBn6v2vh-QosD4EXiEM-QBi9U7Lwbl5E2W9ryKSvjAyAZcbZIL-ig9+WBP6UOoTg0e+C66gOdiQiB5Db460mKtfAyC35oN4ZfGua0WHhRAYQ6CAsN5cN3gfWWx9T5cLSqTaBvCACskBbDOkxHGBMNCyD-3psIhh6DIA6L0SyAEj9jGmPJLg2YwCCFZ1kQoqB19eEADZdHMhdACCmDi6EiLvn4mxgTMGIOfgA1hrj2EyMHPbCi59qGaLvgAdn8fogEZChGoIsbw7JkSDH5L-nEqRbjV5FgYJwtJkCNHeLvrvUpeSNroQcaTcxjDWkBLKR0mYsTBRQSDBCVQhVxCKA0GSREyJUSt2YOwTgKo6AFkBH6TkcoFQ8CIPSVAPBEbqAADLyBMLgbMyAGAMTwEXfs0FH6SiBoBRQ1BWiSjWXshwByjA-zxK81oRgSRmTVIYTePlcBFw5oOHqMh6iynlKQY+2o8zQrgmi0EiknmkwBVhMhXyGT0CvmqW5rRwVkUha0DFQpYXSHhTbal8FBzGWkti+muLJQsvyLSfZPA1kgtJWwclgrqXV3gHC5wkAuWoEZdS2QQQdBsq0hyyAapeo4BNptC5dAiRalFUA5YEqEU7I3rK-0C9eBt0gAAWUEMIPgeIdUFk+XSb5PBcXcmgmZXkGyeVus9fTUEaMrmk1BB8tuyzuB4h5GqMMwgMDSDiHiUNRZzkMGqIwJZHcuD8UDWabO8rXJoEcXm3Vaps64uzrqP1hLBVNILcgBVxbukQ0DWqAA0rgHIihQyEHjYmi5aaM0RuzZyBtTbUDZ11eGrNKzk15sHHQFNgp1SdoYFqctlbN4Ep+XWhdqMKVF2XUWSUa6U1+ljX2hNSah20Eze3FZY7C06CnVqaCEKoUWvgFa7ZpARytFWQxe9kbANqltfAe1jqy0Vsba0KtPNyTfuYJAJ0tjHVbMRVsGtPyjkMFOecy51yCy4fwxcnMRIgMjrndBOguazS-q2GSdU4HIM6o3dnWl9R4PgADEAA) on line 34, I have no idea what could be instantiated with a different subtype or what even the subtype could be.

This is a typescript generated message and I think that `{}` is the default type added to the error message.

[This github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33436) exists but I'm still struggling to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the rest of the code does, but the problem at hand boils down to this:

```
function map2<A, B>(x: A|undefined, fn: (a: A) => B): B|undefined  {
  if (x === undefined) {
      return x;
  } else {
      return fn(x);
  }
}
```

This doesn't check, because `A` can also include `undefined` and TS cannot decide whether to return `A` or `undefined` in the first branch.

This can be easily fixed by telling TS that `A` is never undefined:

```
function map2<A extends {}, B>(x: A|undefined, fn: (a: A) => B): B|undefined  {
  if (x === undefined) {
      return x;
  } else {
      return fn(x);
  }
}
```